# Object identification in landscape Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

My task is to turn an object in an image to pixel styled and this is the image I test with.  [image]

This is the piece of code that I used to crop out the main object in the image which is the hand-like rock. Then turn into pixel styled and save as transparent background.

```
from skimage import io
from pyxelate import Pyx, Pal
# pip install git+https://github.com/sedthh/pyxelate.git --upgrade

import cv2
import numpy as np 

def convert(img): 
    pyx = Pyx(dither='bayer', palette=8)
    pyx.fit(img)
    pix_img  = pyx.transform(img)
    return pix_img

def convert2(img): 
    pass

# apply masking 
def masking(img, kernel_size=1):
    blur = cv2.medianBlur(img, 3)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
        gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,1001, 9)
    
    # apply close morphology
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_size, kernel_size))
    thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    # get bounding box coordinates from the one filled external contour
    filled = np.zeros_like(thresh)

    cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(
        thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    coloured_cnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
    
    cv2.drawContours(filled, [coloured_cnt], 0, 255, -1)
    
    filled = cv2.morphologyEx(filled, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
   
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(coloured_cnt)
    # cv2.imshow('and', img)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    mask = filled[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    return img, mask

def transparentBg(img, mask):
    _, _, channels = img.shape
    if channels < 4:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    img = cv2.bitwise_and(img ,img,mask = mask)

    return img

def main():
    # img = io.imread("2019102514153192166.jpg")  
    # pix_img = convert(img)
    # io.imsave("pixel.png", pix_img)
    
    img = cv2.imread('2019102514153192166.jpg')
    img, mask= masking(img)
    pix_img = convert(img)
    
    pix_img = transparentBg(pix_img, mask) 
    
    cv2.imshow('test', pix_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.imwrite('test.png', pix_img)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

However, I found an app called PixelMe that creates a much better contour for the rock in the app store so I knew there is a better way to crop out the object. Any idea how can i improve the object identification in a landscape image? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: it's likely using AI. you don't. there's your difference. -- it also reduces the palette to look retro, and it downsamples image, then upsamples it with nearest-neighbor sampling, to give the retro "pixel" look.